# post react form state to backend - using nodemailer

Tags: reactjs, axios

I wrote a small component where I am storing form input in state but not sure how I must go about submitting the input with Axios to my backend.

Here is what I have done.

1. Initialize state with empty strings
2. Create function to handle change and store value in state
3. Create switch statement which saves each state of the form
4. Last step I assign my onSubmit function to confirm button which runs function to send this to backend.

I created the function but not sure how to add it to my final step as I have used this outside the function I am using to continue to the next step. Here is my final step which should post the state to my backend:

Hope this makes sense.

```
class FormUserDetails extends Component {
constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
      message: '',
      location: ''
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

async handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const {
      firstName, 
      lastName, 
      email, 
      phone, 
      message, 
      location
    } = this.state

    const form = await axios.post('/api/form', {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      phone,
      message,
      location
    })
  }

continue = e => {

    e.preventDefault();
    // Process Form
    this.props.nextStep();
}

back = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.prevStep();
};

render() {
    const { values: { firstName, lastName, email, phone, message, location } } = this.props;
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <div className="formFields">
                <List>
                    <ListItem
                        primaryText="First Name"
                        secondaryText={firstName}
                    />
                </List>
                <List>
                    <ListItem
                        primaryText="Last Name"
                        secondaryText={lastName}
                    />
                </List>
                <List>
                    <ListItem
                        primaryText="Email"
                        secondaryText={email}
                    />
                </List>
                <List>
                    <ListItem
                        primaryText="Phone"
                        secondaryText={phone}
                    />
                </List>
                <List>
                    <ListItem
                        primaryText="Message"
                        secondaryText={message}
                    />
                </List>
                <List>
                    <ListItem
                        primaryText="Location"
                        secondaryText={location}
                    />
                </List>
                <div className="buttonPosition">
                    <RaisedButton
                        label="confirm"
                        primary={true}
                        style={styles.button}
                        onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}
                        // onClick={this.continue}
                    />
                    <RaisedButton
                        label="back"
                        primary={false}
                        style={styles.button}
                        onClick={this.back}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not be calling onSubmit and onClick on the same button, as this is generally a bad idea. Try combining your code for the two functions into one.

```
<RaisedButton 
  label="confirm"
  primary={true}
  style={styles.button}
  onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}
/>

// Here is the function which should be used to send to backend
async handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  //any logic or processing needed to get form ready to send
  const {firstName, lastName, email, phone, message, location} = this.state
  const form = await axios.post('/api/form', {firstName, lastName, email, phone, message, location})
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this @Ryan. All the logic should be working but I can't get it to submit with Axios, am I missing something? I have updated the original post with the full component.

Comment: Right now I can't see anywhere in your component where you actually use `handleChange`. So as it stands, it appears you would be submitting empty values from state. You are setting variables in your render method to `this.props`, however you are not currently passing `props` to your `FormUserDetails` component at all.